# Fresco - How to check if a file is animated webP or not progrmmatically?

Tags: android, imageview, fresco, image-rendering, animated-webp

I have an image file of webP format. How can I check if it is animated webP or a static image programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Since you added fresco tag to the question, you could use the following utility:

`ImageFormatChecker.getImageFormat_WrapIOException(encodedImage.getInputStream())` should return ImageFormat.WEBP_ANIMATED

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/imagepipeline-base/src/main/java/com/facebook/imageformat/DefaultImageFormatChecker.java#L125

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods to get formats.
Good thing is it identifies animation in webp. (mimeType and extention are same for animated and static type of webp, png, avif images)

```java
InputStream is = ... ;
ImageFormat format = ImageFormatChecker.getImageFormat(is);
```

or

```java
String uri = ... ;
ImageFormat format = ImageFormatChecker.getImageFormat(uri);
```

or

```java
InputStream is = ... ;
ImageFormat format = ImageFormatChecker.getImageFormat_WrapIOException(is);
```

Used Fresco version : 3.1.3.